# gwt java script module not loading - blank page

Tags: java, spring, gwt, maven, jetty

It seems when I manually build my gwt app, and run it on jetty, i get a blank page. I could add tags within the html document and see its content (ex add a table, i would see a table). But it seems like the modules javascript is never loaded.

This would be the command I manually run: mvn gwt:compile jetty:run

When I run my app on GWT Development Mode using their IDE, everything shows up as expected, I see my module being loaded and its contents.

Note I am using the RootLayoutPanel, would I be required to use UI binding?

Answer (score 0):

If Development Mode works but compiled & deployed files do not, well, it looks like a deployment issue. To check, get Firebug for Firefox (or the equivalent tool for your preferred web browser), and check the HTTP requests made when the page is loading - you will probably find that some requests are 404, and that GWT compiles JS hasn't been copied over to the proper spot.